# Trying to find regex lookbehind alternative for GAS

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

seems like lots of questions about this but none fits my needs quite.

I'm using GAS and it doesn't accept regex lookbehind.

I have the regex below which should match :00 after the fifth character. So ignoring the first 5 characters, regardless of what they are. Example might be 22:45:00.

```
(?<=^.....)(:00)/g
```

Any thoughts on how I can achieve this without the lookbehind so it works in Apps Script?

FYI I want to add it within this cumbersome find and replace function

```
function formatChipTimes() {

   var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  spreadsheet.getRange('K:K').activate();
  spreadsheet.getActiveRangeList().setNumberFormat('@')

   var range = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getRange("K2:K");
var v = range.getValues();
for ( var r = 0; r < v.length; ++r) {
  v[r][0] = v[r][0].replace(/\./g, ":");
  v[r][0] = v[r][0].replace(/^0/g, "");
  v[r][0] = v[r][0].replace(/^1:0/g, "6");
  v[r][0] = v[r][0].replace(/^1:1/g, "7");
  v[r][0] = v[r][0].replace(/^1:2/g, "8");
  v[r][0] = v[r][0].replace(/^1:3/g, "9");
  v[r][0] = v[r][0].replace(/^0:/g, "");
  v[r][0] = v[r][0].replace(/^:/g, "");
  v[r][0] = v[r][0].replace(/:0$/g, "");
  v[r][0] = v[r][0].replace(/^\s*$/g, "");

  **v[r][0] = v[r][0].replace(/(?<=^.....)(:00)/g, "");**

  }
range.setValues(v);
}
```

Thanks, appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
v[r][0] = v[r][0].replace(/^(.{5})(:00)/, "$1");
```

This breaks the regular expression into two capture groups, and the `"$1"` just returns the first group.

Comment: Thank you for this. Works as expected. Would never have come up with this myself! ha